# Why is my 3-way merge sort implementation unable to handle sizes above 4

Tags: c++, sorting, merge, mergesort

I am trying to implement a 3 way merge sort, but cannot input a size exceeding 4.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void merge(int arr[], int start, int p1, int p2, int end);

void merge_sort(int arr[], int start, int end) {
  if (start >= end)
    return;

  if (end == start + 1) {
    if (arr[start] > arr[end]) {
      int temp = arr[end];
      arr[end] = arr[start];
      arr[start] = temp;
    }
    return;
  }

  int size = end - start + 1;
  int p1 = size / 3;
  int p2 = 2 * p1;

  merge_sort(arr, start, p1 - 1);
  merge_sort(arr, p1, p2 - 1);
  merge_sort(arr, p2, end);

  merge(arr, start, p1, p2, end + 1);
}

void merge(int arr[], int start, int p1, int p2, int end) {
  int n = end - start;
  int* temp = new int[n];

  int j = start;
  int k = p1;
  int l = p2;
  int i = 0;

  while (true) {
    if (j == p1 || k == p2 || l == end)
      break;
    else
    if (arr[j] < arr[k] && arr[j] < arr[l]) {
      temp[i] = arr[j];
      j++;
    } else if (arr[k] < arr[j] && arr[k] < arr[l]) {
      temp[i] = arr[k];
      k++;
    } else {
      temp[i] = arr[l];
      l++;
    }
    i++;
  }

  int r, s, limit_r, limit_s;

  if (j == p1) {
    r = k;
    s = l;
    limit_r = p2;
    limit_s = end;
  } else if (k == p2) {
    r = j;
    s = l;
    limit_r = p1;
    limit_s = end;
  } else if (l == end) {
    r = j;
    s = k;
    limit_r = p1;
    limit_s = p2;
  }

  while (true) {
    if (r == limit_r || s == limit_s)
      break;

    if (arr[r] < arr[s]) {
      temp[i] = arr[r];
      r++;
    } else {
      temp[i] = arr[s];
      s++;
    }
    i++;
  }

  int final;

  if (r == limit_r)
    final = s;
  else
    final = r;

  while (i < n) {
    temp[i] = arr[final];
    final++;
    i++;
  }

  int test = start;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[test] = temp[i];
    test++;
  }

  delete[] temp;
  return;
}

int main() {

  int size;
  std::cout << "Enter the size of array:";
  std::cin >> size;

  int* mohit = new int[size];

  std::cout << "Enter the elements of the array:";

  for (int m = 0; m < size; m++)
    std::cin >> mohit[m];

  merge_sort(mohit, 0, size - 1);

  std::cout << "The final sorted array is:" << std::endl;

  for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    std::cout << mohit[count] << " ";

  delete[] mohit;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line is doing integer division:

```
int p1 = size / 3;
```

It removes the floating-point part of the number, so it's likely being set to 1 at some point, which makes the value of `p2` equal to 2 perpetually, leading to infinite recursive calls.

To fix this you can change `p1` into a floating point number and make the division return a float. You will also have to set `p2` to the cieling of the division:

```
float p1 = size / 3.0;
int p2 = ceil(2 * p1);
```

Update: There's also something wrong with your merge function. Not sure what it is though.